# how to get integers from an arraylist, use them for calculations and print them

Tags: java

I was trying to create an "algorithm" that tries to get one number from one `ArrayList` and another number from a different `ArrayList`.

The aim is for it to print out one number from the first list and another number from the second list and **the addition of both numbers should add up to a set target**. The target could be given a range.

For example. the first `ArrayList` will have {1,2,3,4,5} and the second one will have 98765 and if the target is 15, the algorithm should print out `9` and `5` at the end or anything that gives is in the target range so although the target is `15`, if the error range is set to `2`, the range will be `13-17`.

I don't know if this makes sense but u can watch this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBuHSRDGZBY&t=241s). I watched the introduction minutes of it and decided to start this project. I'm a beginner as I just started learning java at uni for 3 months now.
ignore the weird variable names.

'''

```
public void closestToTarget(int target, int errorRange, int Aa, int Ab, int Ac, int Ad, int Ae, int Af, int Ba, int Bb, int Bc, int Bd,  int Be, int Bf) 
    {
        numbersone.add(Aa);
        numbersone.add(Ab);
        numbersone.add(Ac);
        numbersone.add(Ad);
        numbersone.add(Ae);
        numbersone.add(Af);

        numberstwo.add(Ba);
        numberstwo.add(Bb);
        numberstwo.add(Bc);
        numberstwo.add(Bd);
        numberstwo.add(Be);
        numberstwo.add(Bf);

        int indexone = 0;
        int indextwo = 0;
        int limitone = numbersone.size();
        int limittwo = numberstwo.size();
        while (indexone < limitone){
            int i = numbersone.get(indexone);
            while (indextwo < limittwo) {
               if (i + numberstwo.get(indextwo) > (target - errorRange) && i + numberstwo.get(indextwo) < (target - errorRange)) {
                   indextwo++;
                   System.out.println(i);
                   System.out.println(numberstwo.get(indextwo));                  
               } 
               else {
                   indextwo++;
               }
            }  
            indexone++;
        }
    } '''
```

Comment: Are the numbers ordered in the arraylist?

Comment: err its just random numbers. so lets say i have 2 sets of numbers, the first set is (-2,4,2,3,5,10) and second is (15,9,3,11,1,7) so i want it to go through the first list, so it takes lets say -2, adds it to every number in the the second list. so -2+15, -2+9....and if the answer is my target(lets say 13) then if -2+15 = 13, it will print out -2 and 15. i put a link for the youtube video that i got this concept from.

Comment: omg actually, nevermid, i debugged and reworked the code and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
'''
        int indexone = 0;
        int indextwo = 0;
        int limitone = numbersone.size();
        int limittwo = numberstwo.size();
        int startrange = target - errorRange;
        int endrange = target + errorRange;
        for (int i : numbersone) {            
            while (indextwo < limittwo) {
                int a = i;
                int b = numberstwo.get(indextwo);     
                int answer = a + b;
                if (answer <= endrange && answer >= startrange) {
                    System.out.println(a + " + " + b + " = " + answer);
                    indextwo++;
                }
                else {
                    indextwo++;
                }
            }
            indextwo = 0;
        }
'''
```